# Thumbnails not being generated from symlinked directory

Tags: media

We have set up a symlink that points outside the webroot. The symlink points to a directory that contains images.

The images are accessible on the site, but Drupal is not creating thumbnails of the images, so these are showing up as broken images.

If the directory is a regular directory and not a link, then the thumbnails are generated correctly.

Why does the symlink not work correctly? Is it related to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1008402)?